# Error trying to run lint on new Definitely Typed definitions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm trying to contribute some new type definitions to Definitely Typed, so I'm following the guide here:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md

But the linter is blowing up in my face.

I tried creating a totally fresh test package with this command:

```
npx dts-gen --dt --name test --template module
```

Then I ran the linter on it with this:

```
npm run lint test
```

When I do that I get the error:

```
Error: Expected `"strictFunctionTypes": true` or `"strictFunctionTypes": false`.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dtslint/bin/checks.js:95:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/dtslint/bin/checks.js:4:58)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try different name than `test`, `npx dts-gen --dt --name xxxx --template module` seems fine :)